# NoSuchMethodError for Card.setText() in XE16

Tags: google-gdk

My Glass updated to XE16 last night and I've been trying out my Glassware on it.  I was able to get some of them running, but I am getting NoSuchMethodErrors on Card.setText() and Card.setFootnote() calls:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card.setText
```

I updated my AndroidStudio projects to use the Glass Development Kit Preview on API 19 (4.4.2) and the compiler doesn't balk on the calls.  The Glassware throws the error when the method is executed.

Anyone else seeing the same problem?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: i can't solve this i am still getting error :(

Comment: ok i solved it just needed to update my GDK to 4.4.2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `Card#setText(String)` method signature changed from expecting a `String` to a `CharSequence`.

You need to make sure to recompile your code with the latest GDK in order to pick up the new reference.

Comment: I had updated AndroidStudio, but missed a spot in the configuration where my project was still pointing to the GDK Sneak Peek.  My bad.  Thanx, @Alain.

Comment: @Alain I am getting this error do i need to update something on eclipse

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji make sure to update to the latest GDK version (in the Android SDK Manager, this is under API level 19 `Glass Development Kit Preview`) and update your project to compile against this target SDK.