# NoSuchMethodError - after update Glass GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I updated my Google Glass GDK from xe12 to xe16. My app was working perfectly well up until the update. Now when I run the app the glass throws:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card.setText
```

I have followed the instructions posted in the discussions below:

[link 1] ([NoSuchMethodError for Card.setText() in XE16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119250/nosuchmethoderror-for-card-settext-in-xe16))

[link 2] ([Google Glass updated to KitKat, but new methods aren't showing up in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144263/google-glass-updated-to-kitkat-but-new-methods-arent-showing-up-in-eclipse))

However I still am not able to run my code.

I have made sure everything is up to date in Eclipse, my project's build target is the Glass Development Kit Preview (KitKat) and I have restarted Eclipse.

Any Suggestions?

here is the code for creating the Card:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import com.Y2014S.MirrorEdge.common_functions.CardScrollViewManager;
import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
private ArrayList<Card> mCards;
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>(10);
    mCards = createCard(mCards, this, "hello");
    CardScrollViewManager ScrollManager = new CardScrollViewManager(mCards);
    mCardScrollView = ScrollManager.createCardScrollView(mCardScrollView,
            getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

public static ArrayList<Card> createCard(ArrayList<Card> mCards,
        final Context appContext, final String headerText)
{
    final Card newCard = new Card(appContext);
    CharSequence cs = headerText;
    newCard.setText(cs);
    mCards.add(newCard);
    return mCards;
}// end of createCard method

}
```

NOTE: I am adding the Card to the ArrayList in the method itself and returning the ArrayList to the Main Activity for later use.

Thanks!

Comment: Would make sense to include your code or snippet for better help here

Answer (score 0):

You now need to use `card.setText(CharSequence xx)`.  By the way, `String` implements `CharSequence`.
You may want to check out the release notes [here](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/4578099?hl=en).

You might try inheriting from Activity .. the following appears to do everything (no errors) .. (but the CardScrollViewManager stuff from your private source:

```
package com.example.stackglasstest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private ArrayList<Card> mCards;
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context x = this;
    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>(10);
    mCards = createCard(mCards, this, "hello");
    CardScrollViewManager ScrollManager = new CardScrollViewManager(mCards);
    mCardScrollView = ScrollManager.createCardScrollView(mCardScrollView,
            getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

public static ArrayList<Card> createCard(ArrayList<Card> mCards,
        final Context appContext, final String headerText)
{
    final Card newCard = new Card(appContext);
    CharSequence cs = headerText;
    newCard.setText(cs);
    mCards.add(newCard);
    return mCards;
}// end of createCard method

}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stackglasstest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.stackglasstest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I added the code as you suggested, still getting the same error. Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: made a new project and ran your code, got: "could not find method com.google.android.glass.app.Card.setText method referenced in com.example.test.MainActivity.createCard"

Comment: I am using the Glass Development preview (4.4.2) as the target build and have Glass Development Kit preview [Android 4.4.2] in the build path

Comment: So I completely reinstalled Eclipse (ADT) and I am still getting the same error as before, I am using the code from the answer above. The code I posted originally was working for about a month now consistently except after the update. I am thoroughly confused is there anything else I can try?

Comment: solution found: Glass was stating that it was up to date however after having a google guide check, that was not true. After legit update. Everything works correctly.

Comment: Glad you found the underlying problem!